# How do I horizontally centre all the entries. Specifically so labels on the left are in centre

Tags: horizontal-alignment, arrays

I have no idea how to show this as latex on here. If somebody could edit this for me then that would be great.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\usepackage{mathtools}

...

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
& Front & Right & Up \\[0.25cm]
\phi_{cube}(F) & \begin{TAB}(e,0.75cm,0.75cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|} 1 & 2 & 3  \\  1 &    & 3  \\  1 & 2 & 3 \end{TAB} &
\begin{TAB}(e,0.75cm,0.75cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|} 1 & 10 & 14  \\  2 &    & 15  \\  3 & 11 & 16 \end{TAB} & 
\begin{TAB}(e,0.75cm,0.75cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|} 1 & 10 & 14  \\  2 &    & 15  \\  3 & 11 & 16 \end{TAB} \\[0.25cm]
\phi_{cube}(FR)& \begin{TAB}(e,0.75cm,0.75cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|} 1 & 10 & 14  \\  2 &    & 15  \\  3 & 11 & 16 \end{TAB} &  
\begin{TAB}(e,0.75cm,0.75cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|} 1 & 10 & 14  \\  2 &    & 15  \\  3 & 11 & 16 \end{TAB} &  
\begin{TAB}(e,0.75cm,0.75cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|} 1 & 10 & 14  \\  2 &    & 15  \\  3 & 11 & 16 \end{TAB}  \\[0.25cm]
\phi_{cube}(FRU^-1) & \begin{TAB}(e,0.75cm,0.75cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|} 1 & 10 & 14  \\  2 &    & 15  \\  3 & 11 & 16 \end{TAB} & 
\begin{TAB}(e,0.75cm,0.75cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|} 1 & 10 & 14  \\  2 &    & 15  \\  3 & 11 & 16 \end{TAB} &
\begin{TAB}(e,0.75cm,0.75cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|} 1 & 10 & 14  \\  2 &    & 15  \\  3 & 11 & 16 \end{TAB}& \
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To display a block of code, after you paste it into the edit window, highlight the code and click on the `{ }` icon.  This will display the data as code, which it does by indenting each line by 4 spaces in the edit window.  To display a short term of code *inline*, surround the `short bit` by leading and trailing grave (backwards) accent.

Comment: Do you want to horizontally or vertically center the contents of the first column?

Comment: In order to make your example code compilable (currently it is not, even if one adds the missing `\begin{document}`), place the contents of the first column in math mode, e.g. `\(\phi_{cube}(F)\)` instead of `\phi_{cube}(F)`.

Comment: Thankyou all! That's useful to know :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the assumption that you want to center the contents of the first column horizontally and vertically, here arw two different suggestions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\usepackage{mathtools}

%%% added: 
\usepackage{adjustbox} % used in the first example only

\usepackage{array} % used in the second example only
\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace} % used in the second example only
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{1.25\tabcolsep} % used in the second example only
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit} % used in the second example only
\begin{document}


horizontally and vertically centered using easytab and adjustbox:

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
& Front & Right & Up \\[0.25cm]
\(\phi_{cube}(F)\)
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.75cm,0.75cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|} 1 & 2 & 3    \\  1 &    & 3   \\  1 & 2  & 3  \end{TAB}}
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.75cm,0.75cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|} 1 & 10 & 14  \\  2 &    & 15  \\  3 & 11 & 16 \end{TAB}} 
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.75cm,0.75cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|} 1 & 10 & 14  \\  2 &    & 15  \\  3 & 11 & 16 \end{TAB}} \\[1.5cm]
\(\phi_{cube}(FR)\)
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.75cm,0.75cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|} 1 & 10 & 14  \\  2 &    & 15  \\  3 & 11 & 16 \end{TAB}} 
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.75cm,0.75cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|} 1 & 10 & 14  \\  2 &    & 15  \\  3 & 11 & 16 \end{TAB}} 
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.75cm,0.75cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|} 1 & 10 & 14  \\  2 &    & 15  \\  3 & 11 & 16 \end{TAB}}  \\[1.5cm]
\(\phi_{cube}(FRU^{-1})\) 
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.75cm,0.75cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|} 1 & 10 & 14  \\  2 &    & 15  \\  3 & 11 & 16 \end{TAB}} 
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.75cm,0.75cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|} 1 & 10 & 14  \\  2 &    & 15  \\  3 & 11 & 16 \end{TAB}} 
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.75cm,0.75cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|} 1 & 10 & 14  \\  2 &    & 15  \\  3 & 11 & 16 \end{TAB}}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\bigskip

horizontally and vertically centered using tabular, cellspace and array:


\begin{tabular}{cccc}
& Front & Right & Up \\[0.25cm]
\(\phi_{cube}(F)\)
  & \begin{tabular}{|*{3}{0{wc{0.35cm}}|}} \hline 1 & 2  & 3  \\ \hline 1 &     & 3  \\ \hline  1 & 2  &  3 \\ \hline \end{tabular} 
  & \begin{tabular}{|*{3}{0{wc{0.35cm}}|}} \hline 1 & 10 & 14 \\ \hline 2 &     & 15 \\ \hline  3 & 11 & 16 \\ \hline \end{tabular} 
  & \begin{tabular}{|*{3}{0{wc{0.35cm}}|}} \hline 1 & 10 & 14 \\ \hline 2 &     & 15 \\ \hline  3 & 11 & 16 \\ \hline \end{tabular} \\[1.5cm]
\(\phi_{cube}(FR)\)
  & \begin{tabular}{|*{3}{0{wc{0.35cm}}|}} \hline 1 & 10 & 14  \\ \hline 2 &    & 15  \\ \hline 3 & 11 & 16 \\ \hline \end{tabular}
  & \begin{tabular}{|*{3}{0{wc{0.35cm}}|}} \hline 1 & 10 & 14  \\ \hline 2 &    & 15  \\ \hline 3 & 11 & 16 \\ \hline \end{tabular}
  & \begin{tabular}{|*{3}{0{wc{0.35cm}}|}} \hline 1 & 10 & 14  \\ \hline 2 &    & 15  \\ \hline 3 & 11 & 16 \\ \hline \end{tabular} \\[1.5cm]
\(\phi_{cube}(FRU^{-1})\) 
  & \begin{tabular}{|*{3}{0{wc{0.35cm}}|}} \hline 1 & 10 & 14  \\ \hline 2 &    & 15  \\ \hline 3 & 11 & 16 \\ \hline \end{tabular}  
  & \begin{tabular}{|*{3}{0{wc{0.35cm}}|}} \hline 1 & 10 & 14  \\ \hline 2 &    & 15  \\ \hline 3 & 11 & 16 \\ \hline \end{tabular}  
  & \begin{tabular}{|*{3}{0{wc{0.35cm}}|}} \hline 1 & 10 & 14  \\ \hline 2 &    & 15  \\ \hline 3 & 11 & 16 \\ \hline \end{tabular} 
\end{tabular}



\end{document}
```

Comment: ahh perfect! Thankyou for your swift response! I don't suppose you know why it causes the alignment to not be in the centre when I use the \begin{TAB} do you? It does the same if i use a matrix or an array instead of tabular too.